# How to save effect of drag on drop in jqtree

Tags: jqtree

I am using drag and drop support of jqtree
http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/examples/drag_and_drop.html

but that effect is temporarily how to save changes ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got answer need to bind move event to jqtree
http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#event-tree-move

like this u can send all information to server

```
$('#tree1').bind(
    'tree.move',
    function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do the move first, and _then_ POST back.
        event.move_info.do_move();
        $.post('your_url', {tree: $(this).tree('toJson')});
    }
);
```

Comment: Not working.. it is still returning default tree (not updated, after drag and drop)